# Schema Tag: The property priceSpecification is not recognized by Google

Tags: schema

`priceSpecification` schema is returning error, how to resolve it? Website has classified listings for used cars posted by users.

Here are schema tags (screenshots attached), unable to paste schema tags code.

```html
<div class="pos-rel" itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Car" >
    <h3 itemprop="name">Toyota Vitz F 1.0 for Sale</h3>
    <div class="price-details generic-dark-grey mb5 mt10"  itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="PKR">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="1585000">
        <span class='pkr'>PKR</span> 15.9 <span>lacs</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs, http://schema.org/Car. Go to bottom of page, click on microdata tag of example. Notice http://schema.org/Offer is part of the person schema. You could do it in two sections like their example or use something like this

```
<!-- Car Details -->
<div id="product" itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Car">
    <h3 itemprop="name">Toyota Vitz F 1.0 for Sale</h3>
    <!-- Seller Details -->
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <strong>Contact Name: </strong> <span itemprop="name givenName">Brent</span>
        <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemref="product">
            <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="PKR">PKR</span>
            <span itemprop="price" content="1585000">15.9</span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice code will validate here: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool